# Got error while trying to get running app icon from ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-package-managers, activity-manager

i'm trying to making a app that shows running app icon in custom listview, and switch to corresponding app when click icon.
i think i should use "ActivityManager.RunningTaskinfo", "PackageManager" and "intent" to make it
so i'm trying.. but i got error on my code.. i got error on "*topActivity*" How can i fix this error?
and how to show "*rtid*" which is the icon that i got from activitymanager and packagemanager
in the custom listview using such as "*Drawable[] images = new Drawable[packs.size()];*"

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(100);
ApplicationInfo appInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(tasks.topActivity.getPackageName(), 0);
Drawable rtid = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
```

Comment: Can you post the LogCat? IIRC, you also need to have a certain permission to get the list of running tasks. Possibly `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"`

Comment: I cannot launch app bacause of the wrong code"topActivity" i'm asking hot to fix it and i already added that permission on my manifest

Comment: Your main problem lies with the fact that you have to get only *one* RunningTaskInfo from the `List` of running tasks. That way `topActivity` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply this a bit.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(100);
List <Drawable> applicationDrawables = new ArrayList <Drawable>();
PackageManager pacMgr = getPackageManager();

  for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo runningTask: tasks)
  {
    try {
      applicationDrawables.add (pacMgr.getApplicationIcon(runningTask.topActivity.getPackageName()));
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Your main problem was that you were trying to get `topActivity` for a `List` rather than just one `RunningTaskInfo` package.

As for displaying the Drawables, you will probably have to [create your own custom adapter](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom), which isn't very hard.

Comment: Thanks you so much for helping me! I already created custom arrayadapter to make custom listview i will try this code soon!

Comment: @sukso No problem! I tried it with an `ImageButton` and it did work. Also, you have to use a `try/catch` block because of the thrown Exception. Lastly, If you have a lot of Running tasks, the next step once you get this working is to use an `AsyncTask` so you don't hold up the UI Thread.